# get customer id in payment method block for new order in admin

Tags: magento-1.8, orders

How could I get the `customer Id` selected in magento admin for `new order` in my `payment method block`

[image: new order - magento admin]

My payment method block extends to `Mage_Payment_Block_Form`

Comment: What do you mean by "selected"?

Comment: @Tim for creating new order admin selects a customer or creates a customer. see screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a single line of code and caused me to wait for hours.

> Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getCustomerId();